# Which is the preferred method of starting a form using HTML helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %> 
... 
<% } %>
```

OR

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %> 
... 
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using both ways to use Html.BeginForm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %> 
... 
<% } %>
```

Just to make sure I get the warning when it isn't closed. But it isn't the greatest use of the using statement.

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx). In terms of rendering, there won't be a difference.

Comment: I've personally taken to using the second method lately. It is more deliberate and formats better with the surrounding markup. Using an IDisposable to close a tag seems a bit cryptic to me.

Comment: @Mitch: That team also came up with something like Html.Text(color => "red") to render an attribute called color to be red. Not sure what the exact syntax is, or which version it made it into.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spark, don't use either. You can easily add your own extensions, [as we've done](http://code.logos.com/blog/web/) at [Logos](http://www.logos.com/).

```
<logos:using form="Html.BeginForm()">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
</logos:using>
```

or

```
<logos:form controller="User" action="Update" routeValues="new { id = 123 }">
    Email: <logos:textbox for="Email" />
</logos:form>
```

Comment: There is actually a cleaner way to do this now: bindings! :-)  http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/bindings

Comment: @Ryan: That is seriously awesome! Thanks for the link!